# How do I deserialize a custom node in Json to c#, whose name keeps changing?

Tags: c#, dynamic, deserialization

Below is a section of json I receive from an endpoint.

If you look at the Json below, 'User-Defined-Network-Name' is a custom node and the name will change each time.

How do I define a C# object for this Json?

```
"addresses": {
            "public": [{
                "version": 6,
                "address": "2005:4600:788e:0910:1a72:81c0:ff03:c7y6"
            },
            {
                "version": 4,
                "address": "197.68.xx.xxx"
            }],
            "private": [{
                "version": 4,
                "address": "10.xx.xx.xxx"
            }],
            "User-Defined-Network-Name": [{
                "version": 4,
                "address": "192.xxx.x.xxx"
            }]
        }
```

This is how far I have come -

```
[Serializable]
    public class Addresses
    {
        public List<Public> @public { get; set; }
        public List<Private> @private { get; set; }
    }
```

Im using 'JavascriptSerializer' class to deserialize json.

Thanks,
Ryan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`addresses` can be deserialized to a type like `Dictionary<string,List<YourClass>>` where `YourClass` holds `version` and `addresss`.

```
var obj = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<Root>(jsonstring);
```

--

```
public class Root
{
    public Dictionary<string,List<VersionAddress>> addresses;
    //Your other fields/properties
}

public class VersionAddress
{
    public string version;
    public string address;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could take advantage of the dynamic nature of C#:

```
// this could come from user input:
string userDefinedName = "User-Defined-Network-Name";
```

string json = "YOUR JSON COMES HERE";

```
var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
dynamic result = serializer.DeserializeObject(json);
int version = result["addresses"][userDefinedName][0]["version"];
string address = result["addresses"][userDefinedName][0]["address"];

Console.WriteLine(version);
Console.WriteLine(address);
```

and if you wanted to loop through the results:

```
foreach (dynamic item in result["addresses"][userDefinedName])
{
    int version = item["version"];
    string address = item["address"];

    Console.WriteLine(version);
    Console.WriteLine(address);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you make network names a dictionary, with key of network name ?
Then you can just iterate over it.

Answer (score -1):

I would not recommend using `JavaScriptSerializer`, as it has been deprecated. If you want a third-party solution, `JSON.Net` is pretty good from what I hear.

However, I'm one that's weird about dependencies, so I typically roll my own if it doesn't exist already. Fortunately, this one isn't too hard due to `DataContractJsonSerializer` from the `System.Runtime.Serialization` namespace.

All you need to do is first define all the objects in a nested fashion:

```
using System.Reflection;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;      // You will have to add a reference
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Json; // to System.Runtime.Serialization.dll

[DataContract]
public class AddressInfo
{ 
  [DataMember(Name = "address")]
  public string Address { get; set; }

  [DataMember(Name = "version")]
  public int Version { get; set; }
}

[DataContract]
public class AddressList
{ 
  [DataMember(Name = "public")]
  public IEnumerable<AddressInfo> Public { get; set; }

  [DataMember(Name = "private")]
  public IEnumerable<AddressInfo> Private { get; set; }

  [DataMember(Name = "User-Defined-Network-Name")]
  public IEnumerable<AddressInfo> UserDefined { get; set; }
}
```

Then a couple helper methods to do the deserialization:

```
// This will change the DataMember.Name at runtime!
// This will only work if you know the node name in advance.
static void SetUserDefinedNodeName(string userDefinedNodeName)
{
  var type = typeof(AddressList);
  var property = type.GetProperty("UserDefined", BindingFlags.Default);
  var attribute = property.GetCustomAttribute<DataMemberAttribute>();

  if (attribute != null)
    attribute.Name = userDefinedNodeName;
}

static T Deserialize<T>(string jsonText, string userDefinedNodeName)
{
  SetUserDefinedNodeName(userDefinedName);

  var jsonBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(jsonText);

  using (var stream = new MemoryStream(jsonBytes))
  {
    var serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(T));  
    var obj = serializer.ReadObject(stream) as T;

    return obj;
  }
}
```

Then you use it like so:

```
var jsonText = // get your json text somehow
var addressList = Deserialize<AddressList>(jsonText);
```

Comment: OP says `'User-Defined-Network-Name' is a custom node and the name will change each time`

Comment: A JSON field that changes its name each time is a poor design of the service he is subscribing to. Regardless of the method he uses to parse it, it will be an annoying catch. I don't see how my solution here isn't helpful as a starting point.

Comment: Because `User-Defined-Network-Name` is not available at compile time.

Comment: I have added a method which will allow the `DataMemberAttribute.Name` property to be changed dynamically before parsing. If the name is predictable, then this will work.

Comment: SiLo, to `predict` it, you have to parse the input string somehow (which can also be named as `deserialization`). How do you plan to predict it?

Comment: I meant, perhaps it is a setting that the user sets themselves (similar to a wireless network name), or perhaps is a portion of the query going out to the web service. Something variable, but reliable given certain inputs. If the value is unpredictable until the stream is acquired, then no my solution will not work. However, it would be difficult to parse that in general.

Comment: BTW: You can not declare a property named `Address` in class `Address`

Comment: Also suppose two threads try to deserialize with different `User-Defined-Network-Name`s at the same time.  This would also cause troubles.